# Vuepress - How to get the processed image filename

Tags: vuepress

In Vuepress, when adding an image to our markdown, it will process the image and add a hash to its filename.

For example, the markdown:

```
![My Image](../images/my-image.png)
```

Will result in the HTML:

```html
<img src="/assets/img/my-image.03c0601d.png" alt="My Image">
```

When the image is just used in the page, this isn't a problem, since the resulted HTML will use the processed image filename.

The problem is when we want to add a link to this image.

For example, the markdown:

```
[![My Image](../images/my-image.png)](../images/my-image.png)
```

results in the HTML:

```html
<a href="/assets/img/my-image.png">
    <img src="/assets/img/my-image.03c0601d.png" alt="My Image">
</a>
```

which is obviously a broken link, since the processed image filename is not `my-image.png`, but `my-image.03c0601d.png` instead.

How can I save this "processed" image filename into a variable to be used in a link?

Or, in other words, how could I handle this scenario where I want to open the processed image on its own?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Updating the VuePress configuration file (`config.js`) with the code below fixed it for me. The links are now updated with the correct image path including the hash.

```js
chainWebpack: (config, isServer) => {
  config.module.rule('vue').uses.store.get('vue-loader').store.get('options').transformAssetUrls = {
    video: ['src', 'poster'],
    source: 'src',
    img: 'src',
    image: ['xlink:href', 'href'],
    a: 'href'
  }
}
```

Example:

The markdown:

```
[![My Image](../images/my-image.png)](../images/my-image.png)
```

Results in the HTML:

```html
<a href="/assets/img/my-image.03c0601d.png">
    <img src="/assets/img/my-image.03c0601d.png" alt="My Image">
</a>
```

Reference: https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/issues/826